# Counting rows in nested groups

Tags: r

This is an extension of a previous question that I have asked. Unfortunately, I have not successfully modified previous code to fit this new requirement.

I have a data set with a nested group design and need to sequentially count sub-groups. The example data frame below illustrates the structure of my data set. `GROUP_LENGTH` is the number of rows within the same `GROUP` and note that the rows within these groups are counted sequentially (i.e., `a1` and `c2` occur multiple times). `GROUP_LENGTH` sequentially numbers the rows within each `GROUP_LENGTH`.

My issues arise with `SEQ_SAMPLE`. My current code sequentially numbers the `GROUP` for the whole data set, but I need the code to sequentially number the `GROUP` within each `SITE` and `SAMPLE` (see `Result` dataframe).

I have tried variations of this code using `ave`, which has not worked. I also see how to use a `for` loop, but prefer to avoid this if possible as I have a large data set. I am also open to all solutions, but prefer `base package` solutions as I want to avoid having to load packages.
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
df <- read.table(text = "SITE   SAMPLE  TIME    GROUP
a   1   1   a1
a   1   2   a2
a   1   3   a2
a   1   4   a3
a   2   1   b1
a   2   2   b1
a   2   3   b1
a   2   4   b3
a   2   5   b3
a   2   6   b3
b   1   1   c1
b   1   2   c2
b   1   3   c3
b   1   4   c4
b   1   5   c4
b   2   1   d1
b   2   2   d2
b   2   3   d3
", header = TRUE)

result <- read.table(text = "SITE   SAMPLE  TIME    GROUP   GROUP_LENGTH    GROUP_SEQ   SEQ_SAMPLE
a   1   1   a1  1   1   1
a   1   2   a2  2   1   2
a   1   3   a2  2   2   2
a   1   4   a3  1   1   3
a   2   1   b1  3   1   1
a   2   2   b1  3   2   1
a   2   3   b1  3   3   1
a   2   4   b3  3   1   2
a   2   5   b3  3   2   2
a   2   6   b3  3   3   2
b   1   1   c1  1   1   1
b   1   2   c2  1   1   2
b   1   3   c3  1   1   3
b   1   4   c4  2   1   4
b   1   5   c4  2   2   4
b   2   1   d1  1   1   1
b   2   2   d2  1   2   2
b   2   3   d3  1   3   3
", header = TRUE)

# First two lines of the code work fine....but it is the last line where the bug lines...
df$GROUP_LENGTH = with(rle(paste(df$SAMPLE, df$GROUP)), rep(lengths, lengths))
df$GROUP_SEQ = sequence(rle(paste(df$SAMPLE, df$GROUP))$lengths)

df$SEQ_SAMPLE = with(rle(paste(df$SITE, df$SAMPLE, df$GROUP)), rep(seq_along(values),lengths))
```

Comment: Are last two values of `result$GROUP_SEQ` correct? Shouldn't these be both `1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `ave` and create unique number for `GROUP` within each `SITE` and `SAMPLE`.

```
df$SEQ_SAMPLE = with(df, as.integer(ave(GROUP, SITE, SAMPLE, 
               FUN = function(x) with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))))


identical(df$SEQ_SAMPLE, result$SEQ_SAMPLE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This code definitvely works, but I just realized that my example data set is missing one key element...which is repeating `GROUP` within the same `SITE` and `SAMPLE`. For example, is we replaced the `GROUP` in row 3 (which is "a3") with "a1", then the `SEQ_SAMPLE` changes to 1 and it should be 3. I can repost the question if needed, but would be happy to see a potential solution via the comments. Appologies for not including this key detail in my example.

Comment: Do you mean row 4? I updated the answer to use `rle` to solve this issue. @Vesuccio

Comment: Good eyes....yes I should have said row 4. Your solution works....thanks legend! You have answered several of my questions in the past several weeks and I greatly appreciate it. Take care.

Comment: Really great answer this was.

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse solution, which is very easy as it is direct application of three basic functions in dplyr,

- `n()` returning count of rows
- `row_number()` which numbers the rows requentially
- `dense_rank()` which provides each element an identity

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(GROUP) %>%
  mutate(GROUP_LENGTH = n(),
         GROUP_SEQ = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(SITE, SAMPLE) %>%
  mutate(SEQ_SAMPLE = dense_rank(GROUP)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 18 x 7
   SITE  SAMPLE  TIME GROUP GROUP_LENGTH GROUP_SEQ SEQ_SAMPLE
   <chr>  <int> <int> <chr>        <int>     <int>      <int>
 1 a          1     1 a1               1         1          1
 2 a          1     2 a2               2         1          2
 3 a          1     3 a2               2         2          2
 4 a          1     4 a3               1         1          3
 5 a          2     1 b1               3         1          1
 6 a          2     2 b1               3         2          1
 7 a          2     3 b1               3         3          1
 8 a          2     4 b3               3         1          2
 9 a          2     5 b3               3         2          2
10 a          2     6 b3               3         3          2
11 b          1     1 c1               1         1          1
12 b          1     2 c2               1         1          2
13 b          1     3 c3               1         1          3
14 b          1     4 c4               2         1          4
15 b          1     5 c4               2         2          4
16 b          2     1 d1               1         1          1
17 b          2     2 d2               1         1          2
18 b          2     3 d3               1         1          3
```